# Declare JSON encoder on the class itself for Pydantic

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I have the following class:

```py
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, x: str):
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: str) -> "Thing":
        return cls(v)
```

Due to the validator method I can use this class as custom field type in a Pydantic model:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from thing import Thing

class Model(BaseModel):
    thing: Thing
```

But if I want to serialize to JSON I need to set the [`json_encoders`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders) option on the Pydantic model:

```py
class Model(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
             Thing: str
        }
    thing: Thing
```

Now Pydantic can serialize `Thing`s to JSON and back. But the config is in two places: Partly on the `Model` and partly on the class `Thing`. I'd like to set it all on `Thing`.

Is there any way to set the `json_encoders` option on `Thing` so Pydantic knows how to handle it transparently?

Note that `Thing` is minimized here: It has a lot of logic and I'm not just trying to declare a custom `str` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually an issue that goes much deeper than Pydantic models in my opinion. I found [this ongoing discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/introduce-a-json-magic-method/21768) about whether a standard protocol  with a method like `__json__` or `__serialize__` should be introduced in Python.

The problem is that Pydantic is confined by those same limitations of the standard library's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, in that encoding/serialization logic for custom types is separated from the class itself.

Whether or not the broader idea of introducing such a protocol makes sense, we can piggy-back off of it a little to define a customized version of [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) that checks for the presence of e.g. a `__serialize__` method and uses that as the `default` function to serialize the object. (See the [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) documentation for an explanation of the `default` parameter.)

Then we can set up a custom base model with the [`Config.json_dumps`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation) option set to that function. That way all child models would automatically fall back to that for serialization (unless overridden by the `encoder` argument to the [`BaseModel.json`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson) method for example).

Here is an example:

`base.py`

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from json import dumps as json_dumps
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel


def json_dumps_extended(obj: object, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    default: Callable[[object], object] = kwargs.pop("default", lambda x: x)

    def custom_default(to_encode: object) -> object:
        serialize_method = getattr(to_encode, "__serialize__", None)
        if serialize_method is None:
            return default(to_encode)
        return serialize_method()  # <-- already bound to `to_encode`

    return json_dumps(obj, default=custom_default, **kwargs)


class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
    class Config:
        json_dumps = json_dumps_extended
```

`application.py`

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable, Iterator

from .base import BaseModel


class Thing:
    def __init__(self, x: str) -> None:
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.x

    def __serialize__(self) -> str:  # <-- this is the magic method
        return self.x

    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls) -> Iterator[Callable[..., Thing]]:
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v: str) -> Thing:
        return cls(v)


class Model(BaseModel):
    thing: Thing
    num: float = 3.14


instance = Model(thing=Thing("foo"))
print(instance.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "thing": "foo",
    "num": 3.14
}
```

Note for Python `<3.9` users: Import the [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) and [`Iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterator) types from `typing` instead of `collections.abc`.

---

#### PS

If you want to be able to re-use this approach to serialization in more places than just the base model, it may be a good idea to put a bit more effort into the types. A `runtime_checkable` custom protocol for our `__serialize__` method may be useful.

Also we can make the `json_dumps_extended` method a bit less clunky by using `functools.partial`.

Here is a slightly more sophisticated version of the suggested `base.py`:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import partial
from json import dumps as json_dumps
from typing import Any, Optional, Protocol, TypeVar, overload, runtime_checkable

from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel

T = TypeVar("T")
T_co = TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)
Func1Arg = Callable[[object], T]


@runtime_checkable
class Serializable(Protocol[T_co]):
    def __serialize__(self) -> T_co: ...


@overload
def serialize(obj: Serializable[T_co]) -> T_co: ...


@overload
def serialize(obj: Any, fallback: Func1Arg[T]) -> T: ...


def serialize(obj: Any, fallback: Optional[Func1Arg[Any]] = None) -> Any:
    if isinstance(obj, Serializable):
        return obj.__serialize__()
    if fallback is None:
        raise TypeError(f"Object not serializable: {obj}")
    return fallback(obj)


def _id(x: T) -> T: return x


def json_dumps_extended(obj: object, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    custom_default = partial(serialize, fallback=kwargs.pop("default", _id))
    return json_dumps(obj, default=custom_default, **kwargs)


class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
    class Config:
        json_dumps = json_dumps_extended
```

Another alternative might have been to just monkey-patch `JSONEncoder.default` directly. But without further configurations Pydantic seems to still perform the type checks itself and prevent serialization before that method is even called.

I don't think we have a better option, until some standard serialization protocol (at least for JSON) is introduced.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of going this route but it's nice to see such a well worked example: you even added the types in I left out from laziness. I was hoping there was some protocol or magic method I'd missed but it's just not there atm: I'll probably implement it myself like this.

Comment: @2e0byo Sure thing. I added a slightly more sophisticated/reusable version just now. But I don't think there is anything more elegant we can do right now. And I don't see a standardized protocol for serialization making it into Python anytime soon.

Comment: Well this remains an excellent reference answer until we do, and I couldn't find anything saying 'no, there's no protocol for that'.  Thanks!